# Why does Django Admin calls UserCreationForm save method with commit=False?

Tags: django, django-admin

Where does the django admin actually saves it's models?

I wanted to print some model fields that are only created after saving occurs, but UserCreationForm save method always gets called with commit=False and seem to return user so the save occurs somewhere else.

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    ...
    def save(self, commit=True):
        # django admin calling this with commit=False... save occurs somewhere else.
        ...
        if commit:
            print("this never gets printed")
            user.save()

        # line below prints nothing
        print(user.field_set_after_model_is_saved)

        return user
```

p.s: my model is getting saved normally, just not where I expected.

Comment: Please show the model admin where you are using the form, and how you are registering that model admin.

Answer (score -1):

> This save() method accepts an optional commit keyword argument, which
>   accepts either True or False. If you call save() with commit=False,
>   then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the
>   database. In this case, it’s up to you to call save() on the resulting
>   model instance. This is useful if you want to do custom processing on
>   the object before saving it, or if you want to use one of the
>   specialized model saving options. commit is True by default.

from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/).

When you use `commit=False`, you're not saving in database yet, it lets you to manage the object before saving.

For example:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def save(self):
        # Sets username to email before saving
        user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = user.email
        user.save()
        return user
```

If first save don't use `commit=False`, it saved twice and it represent more database operations. 
In your case I think you can use post_save signals, look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save)